# extern Keyword in C++ with file header file inclusion

Tags: c++, extern

I have started learning C++. i came across one of the use case like below but could not explore it more. please let me know your views.

```
extern "C" {
    #include "file1.h"
    #include "file2.h"
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a mistake if `file1.h` or `file2.h` include any standard headers, even indirectly

Answer (score 0):

First you should kown what is function overloading in c++ which is not in existence in c.
In order to support function overloading,
c++ compiler need to translate functions with the same name but different function signature into different symbol names.
However, you may invoke some libs written by c++ in a c program.But because of the different function name translation mechanism，there will be some error when invoking c++-style functions in a c program.
So, the `extern c` means i want the c++ compiler translate the function name like the c complier does.Thus it's ok to invoke c++ libs in your c program.

Comment: The term you are describing is often called "Name Mangling" and less often called "Name Decoration". Frankly I don't know which is official or more correct.

Comment: I have seen "Name Decoration" in some chinese books.Because of my poor English,so i described the term in my own way.